# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo

I try to change render when there is a change with `useEffect` and I have this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')". when I log the console print the array and its values.

```js
  const listMemo = useMemo(() => ({ list }), [list]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(list)   //Print the array 
    console.log(listMemo)   //Print the array
    listMemo.list.array.forEach((element, i) => {
      //********************************
      //*************************************** */
      }
    });
  }, [listMemo]);
```

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(list)` and `console.log(listMemo)`

Comment: You can see the output click to "output console log"

Comment: Dont put a screenshot in there. Copy and paste the `JSON.stringify` output of it. And formit it well.

Comment: [{"index":0,"nomProduit":"","numProduit":"","pa":"","pv":"","qte":1,"total":0}]
                                                                                                                                       {"list":[{"index":0,"nomProduit":"","numProduit":"","pa":"","pv":"","qte":1,"total":0}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listMemo.list.forEach(`

NOT `listMemo.list.array.forEach(` - remove `array` and one of dots.